# Installing windows 7 through usb keeps looping

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, usb

Okay so, I am trying to install windows 7 (after I accadently stopped it the first time when I downloaded it on the laptop with xp itsself causing windows xp to be missing components) using a usb to boot from. When It is allmost done installing and it starts up again \the installation menu pops up again. It just keeps doing this, like looping. I have allready tried changing the boot order and pulling out the usb, but when I do that I just get a black screen telling me to reboot and select proper boot device.

Help?? :,(

Comment: Instead of changing it in the bios I would see if your computer has a 1 time boot change option.  On HP its F9 on asus mobo its usually F8.

Comment: yeah escape on mine, but that doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Remove the USB just after your CPU turns off for a moment while restarting. You must do it before BIOS screen appears.